# Зигзаговый border в CSS

Tags: css, css3, style, border

Нужно сделать зигзаговую границу блока (из треугольников).

Как это лучше реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете на картинке показать как это выглядеть должно?

Comment: Я добавил картинку

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, хватит уже пытаться закрыть всё подряд.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Картинка здесь как приложение (для наглядности), а текст вопроса можно чуть-чуть отредактировать (что я и сделал).

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12031328/1548895

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, просто в очереди полно вопросов с картинками, закрытие которых инициировано тобой. Я считаю неправильным выискивать такие вопросы и пытаться закрывать.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```css
.zig-zag {
  background: #1ba1e2;
  position: relative;
}

.zig-zag:after {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 20px, #1ba1e2 0),
              linear-gradient( 45deg, transparent 20px, #1ba1e2 0);
  background-position: left bottom;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}


/* Просто оформление, для зиг-зага не нужно */

body {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="zig-zag">
  <h1>Рамка зубцами</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 5):

<sub>Перевод [моего ответа на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44674571/1548895):</sub>

Улучшенный минимальный CSS:

```css
div {
  background: #1ba1e2;
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #1ba1e2 0) 0 50%,
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #1ba1e2 0) 0 50%;
  background-size: 30px 30px;
}

/* Стили чисто для демонстрации */
h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Zig Zag Borders</h1>
</div>
```

Если вы хотите удалить дублирующиеся значения вы можете также использовать [CSS variables, также известные как Custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*). Они работают везде, кроме IE.

```css
:root {
  --background-color: #1ba1e2;
  --zigzag-item-size: 30px;
}

div {
  background: var(--background-color);
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--zigzag-item-size);
  background:
    linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, var(--background-color) 0) 0 50%,
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, var(--background-color) 0) 0 50%;
  background-size: var(--zigzag-item-size) var(--zigzag-item-size);
}

/* Стили чисто для демонстрации */
h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Zig Zag Borders</h1>
</div>
```

#### Небольшая заметка:

Я использую `0` как ступенях градиентов, чтобы не дублировать предыдущие значения, так как по [спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#color-stop-syntax) ступенька градиента не может быть меньше предыдущего значения.

> If a color-stop has a position that is less than the specified position of any color-stop before it in the list, set its position to be equal to the largest specified position of any color-stop before it.

Comment: У меня оно рисуется уродливо http://i.imgur.com/uHCs8Jc.png http://i.imgur.com/zzrQCG1.png

Comment: @andreymal А это в каком браузере и при каких значениях? Первый пример или второй?

Comment: Первый и второй соответственно, фаерфокс на убунточке

Comment: @andreymal К сожаленью, не могу воспроизвести такое на Windows, в том числе на Firefox. А Ubuntu у меня нет. Если найдёте фикс для этой проблемы, то я обновлю свой ответ.

Comment: @andreymal А в Chrome тоже есть такая проблема? На Windows в Chrome всё ок, если что.

Comment: В хроме тоже, ага

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать треугольный бордер, если это устроит. css3 shapes

```
    #up-triangle {
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   border-bottom: 120px solid green; 
   border-left: 60px solid transparent; 
   border-right: 60px solid transparent; 
}
```